# "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when calling function

Tags: javascript

I get the following error when I click my refresh button:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at getRandomImage (index.html:85)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:11)
```

See this snippet:

```js
var myArray = new Array();

getRandomImage(myArray, "");

function getRandomImage(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || 'C:/Users/Owen/Desktop/1-800MemeLine-master/memes/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];
    var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}
```

```html
<form>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="getRandomImage()" VALUE="More MEME plz">
    </INPUT>
</form>
```

It works fine with the button refreshing the page but most of the people on my website have bad internet which takes a long time to reload the page so only loading the image and not the background and text and unnecessary things.

Link to github REPO: https://github.com/odude102/1-800MemeLine/blob/master/index.html

Comment: In the `onClick`, you're calling `getRandomImage()` without any arguments, thus `imgAr` in your function is undefined, and then you get a TypeError when trying to read the length of undefined.

Comment: Could you please provide some demo code o do not understand what you are saying how would I define imgAr

Comment: Are you saying I should do getRandomImage(imgAr)

Comment: No, since you don't any array to provide in the onclick. From your code, it seems your array is pretty static, so you don't need to pass it as an argument. I've added an answer which solves your issue, but it does not necessarily provide a good answer (or good code for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but it fixes your problem:

```
var myArray = new Array();
var path =  'C:/Users/Owen/Desktop/1-800MemeLine-master/memes/';
getRandomImage();

function getRandomImage() {
  var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * myArray.length );
  var img = myArray[ num ];
  var imgStr = '<img src="' + path + img + '" alt = "">';
  document.write(imgStr);
  document.close();
}
```

Comment: it removes the background and image switching button is there a way to put it in a iframe or something